# How do I export an existing play framework into Heroku?

Tags: eclipse, heroku, playframework

I have been reading and following: http://eclipse-plugin.herokuapp.com/
to export my existing play applications to Heroku.

When running **heroku create**, **git push heroku master** in my terminal everything works
like a charm and my project is created and I can browse it at: xxx.herokuapp.com.
But when I enter Eclipse the project is not "hooked" to Heroku. E.g I'm not able 
to **Push to Upstream**

If I go the other way and import the Heroku project with Eclipse, the project is downloaded and "hookup" to Heruko but then the project is located in my git repo and not workspace.

So my question is:
How do I connect my project that are located in my workspace to Heroku so that it's treated like a Eclipse Heroku app?

**EDIT:**

There is no share option:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup the project so you can do the Git operations from Eclipse, you need to do the following:

1. Right-click on the project in the `Project Explorer` and select `Team`
2. Select `Share Project...`
3. Select `Git` and then `Next`
4. Leave the defaults as they are and select `Finish`

To upload the app to Heroku, do the following (after your changes are committed to the Git repo):

1. Right-click on the project in the `Project Explorer` and select `Team`
2. Go to the `Remote` sub-menu and select `Push...`
3. Leave the defaults as they are (the Heroku Remote Git repo should be selected) and select `Finish`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I'm having trouble locating Share Project. See screenshot.

Comment: In this case Eclipse has already setup the Git repo for the project.  Can you push to the Heroku remote?

Comment: Yes that works! Perfect! Thank you! Is it possible for you to update your answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Did the second half of the instructions work to fix your problem?  Do you want me to adjust the answer to just have that section?

Comment: I think we should keep both =)!